# sotimeout not working in a multipart http post on android 2.1

Tags: android

I am using the apache httpclient that ships with the android sdk to upload a file on server using multipart http post. The problem is that when i turn off the wifi connection on my device and the device has no internet access and event after setting the sotimeout and connectiontimeout the code hangs on the `httpclient.execute()` statement indefinitely and it happens every single time.

my code is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 5000);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout( httpclient.getParams(), 5000 ); 

HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(httpclient.getParams(), 8192);

HttpPost("http://myurl");

File file = new File(fileAbsolutePath);
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
mpEntity.addPart("uploadedfile", cbFile);
httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
if(!backupCancel)
{
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Actually transferring file>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Assuming u have a httpClient object which is a instance of AndroidHttpClient or DefaultHttpClient

```
HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, Timeout in milli seconds);
```

httpParams you get is a reference object so it executing setIntParameter will fix the issue

Unless you real have a special requirement for custom timeouts prefer using AndroidHttpClient it is very useful and solves most of our problems :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
HttpParams lHttpParams = new  BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(lHttpParams, 3000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(lHttpParams, 3000);
```

Best Regards,
~Anup

Comment: have u ever tried this...i have tried all possible combinations nothing seems to set the sotimeout properly. It never kicks in when the device has not internet connectivity. :(

Comment: yes what you gave works jst fine...actually the device i was checking on was a cracked one on which 2.2 was installed forcefully...may b due to that when i checked on other devices it worked like a charm..thanx